# Reading MAC address to shell variable causes strange behavior

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, for-loop

I am running this script

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 2 ]
then
   echo argument one must be the site number
   echo argument two must be the vlan
fi

site=$1
vlan=$2
deviceNum=1

while read MACLine
do
   echo arp -s 10.${site}.${vlan}.${deviceNum} "${MACLine}" temp
   deviceNum=`expr $deviceNum + 1`
done < MAC.txt
```

And I am using this as the input

```
AC:CC:8E:0A:EF:67
AC:CC:8E:0B:AE:4B
AC:CC:8E:0B:CF:17
00:40:8C:FC:6D:86
00:40:8C:FA:61:B1
AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:C3
AC:CC:8E:0B:E5:2B
AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:D7
AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:DF
```

I get this strange input... when I copy paste into windows (keep reading)

```
arp -s 10.10.20.1 AC:CC:8E:0A:EF:67
 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.2 AC:CC:8E:0B:AE:4B
 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.3 AC:CC:8E:0B:CF:17
 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.4 00:40:8C:FC:6D:86
 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.5 00:40:8C:FA:61:B1
 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.6 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:C3
 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.7 AC:CC:8E:0B:E5:2B
 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.8 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:D7
 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.9 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:DF
 temp
```

In the Ubuntu shell, however, I see the following

```
temps 10.10.20.1 AC:CC:8E:0A:EF:67
temps 10.10.20.2 AC:CC:8E:0B:AE:4B
temps 10.10.20.3 AC:CC:8E:0B:CF:17
temps 10.10.20.4 00:40:8C:FC:6D:86
temps 10.10.20.5 00:40:8C:FA:61:B1
temps 10.10.20.6 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:C3
temps 10.10.20.7 AC:CC:8E:0B:E5:2B
temps 10.10.20.8 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:D7
temps 10.10.20.9 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:DF
```

What is the method to this madness?

---

**NOTE**: this has something to do with the colons. If you replace the MAC addresses with something like "hello...hello...hello", it works as expected

Comment: paste your script in http://www.shellcheck.net/ There you can see that you've got some [not decisive but important] warnings

Comment: @fedorqui I made the corrections it recommended, however, as you said so yourself, they did not fix the problem

Comment: @Mr.Llama you were right, it was the input file which was dos format

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have carriage return characters in your input file.  Do `dos2unix` on the input file and that should fix your issue.

Comment: Nope it was not that. I can confirm that it is a UNIX file, and even with the call to `dos2unix`, it still does not work.

Comment: Man I feel stupid...it was the input file that was dos.

Comment: Carriage returns are wonky.  They'll reset the cursor to the start of the line and start overwriting text.  Thats why your output lines start with `temps` because it's `arp -s` overwritten with `[space]temp`.

Answer (score 1):

The madness is called Windows.
I took your MAC address list and pasted into a file on Ubuntu and run the script.

Output:

```
arp -s 10.10.20.1 AC:CC:8E:0A:EF:67 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.2 AC:CC:8E:0B:AE:4B temp
arp -s 10.10.20.3 AC:CC:8E:0B:CF:17 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.4 00:40:8C:FC:6D:86 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.5 00:40:8C:FA:61:B1 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.6 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:C3 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.7 AC:CC:8E:0B:E5:2B temp
arp -s 10.10.20.8 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:D7 temp
arp -s 10.10.20.9 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:DF temp
```

Then converted into Windows madness and run it again:

```
$ unix2dos MAC.txt
$ bash run_mac.sh 10 20
 temps 10.10.20.1 AC:CC:8E:0A:EF:67
 temps 10.10.20.2 AC:CC:8E:0B:AE:4B
 temps 10.10.20.3 AC:CC:8E:0B:CF:17
 temps 10.10.20.4 00:40:8C:FC:6D:86
 temps 10.10.20.5 00:40:8C:FA:61:B1
 temps 10.10.20.6 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:C3
 temps 10.10.20.7 AC:CC:8E:0B:E5:2B
 temps 10.10.20.8 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:D7
 temps 10.10.20.9 AC:CC:8E:0F:B1:DF
```

Voila...

Comment: I imagine that the `unix2dos` command was created exclusively for such situations.